# Can't use w3school HTML include

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here's the link to the original w3school article about HTML include using their .js file [link](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp).

I literally copied everything from the w3school example, but got this error :

> w3school.js:131 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/KBS-3/Desktop/project_1/html/header.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Here's my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 

<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and content.html

```html
<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
```

Any ideas to resolve this ?

Comment: nah, i tried to copy the content of their js to my local file, not working tho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error suggests, you are trying to include a local html file `file:///C:/Users/KBS-3/Desktop/project_1/html/header.html.` using javascript which is not permitted due to security reasons. (Imagine, if it were allowed, websites could read any of your local hard drive data).

Solution: Move your website to `localhost` i.e. use `XAMP` or a real server and you'll be fine.

Comment: so, i just can't run it using chrome, but when i deploy this website online, it will work ?

Comment: @RickyGauni You can't run it as local files. Issue is not specific to chrome. And you don't have to put it online, you can also use a local server like XAMP to test it.

Comment: actually as the previous answer suggest, i had no problem opening it using mozilla .-. but i will try to learn all about XAMP later today, thanks

Comment: @RickyGani That's right. Mozilla's policy on the issue is  much relaxed as compared to Chrome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs

Comment: Well, anyway, thanks for clearing up this problem to me, looking forward to learn about XAMP :)